# Parse.initialize breaking Angular Cordova app in iOS simulation

Tags: angularjs, cordova, parse-platform, ionic-framework

So I have an app in angular with cordova, that works as expected when served to a local web host, pushing and pulling the login data from parse.com.

But, when I compile and emulate in an IOS emulator, it appears that the command

```
parse.initialize("453ioejblahgf3oi5j35p","f30903959fblahblah");
```

is making $state.go fail to work.

:(

Upon closer inspection, it seems as though Parse.initialize("faerfaerfaerf";"aefaerfeafaer"); is putting a stop to all code that comes after it --

```
$scope.registerNowClick = function (user) {
        //Copy the user to $scope.tmpUser
        $scope.tmpUser = angular.copy(user);


                // PARSE INITILIZATION CALL     Parse.initialize("Zmqvefjaeifai34jofewOvRDxfNdoxH", "HlzTePUSi3fja305f0j341");
        alert('Register Now was clicked w/ Email:' +     $scope.tmpUser.email);

        // PARSE ADD A USER
        var user = new Parse.User();
        user.se blah blah
```

If I move the alert above the parse.init, it fires. But when it's after the parse.init, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is `interpreted` language. Meaning that, any `run-time` errors wont halt the program, until that particular line is reached.

Looking at your problem, it looks like `Object Parse` is not `defined`. Have you included any `parse.js` files that it may require? Move `Parse.initialize()` to the end of the script so that it wont halt the rest of the code from executing.

Answer (score 0):

I have put my Parse initialization in a separate `UserService.init()` that must be resolved at app startup.

```
.state('tab', {
    url: "/tab",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html",
    resolve: {
        user: function (UserService) {
            var value = UserService.init();
            // alert(value); // for debugging
            return value;
        }
    }
})
```

Here is a snippet of  the `UserService` code

```
   init: function () {

    var value = null;

    var deferred = $q.defer();
    // if initialized, then return the activeUser
    if (parseInitialized === false) {
        Parse.initialize(ParseConfiguration.applicationId, ParseConfiguration.javascriptKey);
        parseInitialized = true;
        console.log("parse initialized in init function");
    }

    setTimeout(function () {
        var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
        if (currentUser) {
            deferred.resolve(currentUser);
        } else {
            deferred.reject({error: "noUser"});
        }
    }, 100);
    return deferred.promise;
},
```

The complete solution is here ... https://github.com/aaronksaunders/dcww